# Returning string from xmllint/xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I have the following xml excerpt and what I want is just the string 2014.4.0.0008 in the Version tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExternalMetadataPack xmlns="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/externalMetadata" schemaVersion="1.0">
    <PackInfo>
        <Name>Main External List Mappings</Name>
        <PackID>main-external-mappings</PackID>
        <Version>2014.4.0.0008</Version>
    </PackInfo>
</ExternalMetadataPack>
```

I've tried a few things and gotten as far as this:

```
xmllint --xpath "//PackInfo/@Version[local-name()='ExternalMetadataPack']" externalmetadata.xml
```

But nothing seems to be working. This says that the XPath set is empty and if I include string() in the --xpath parameter then it just doesn't return anything.

Comment: What do you want to fetch ?

Comment: Your XPath seems totally wrong

Comment: I'm looking for the contents of the <Version> tag which in this example is 2014.4.0.0008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (ignoring the NS) :

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="Version"]/text()' file.xml
```

AFAIK, it's not possible to set a default NS with the --xpath switch, so with the --shell one :

```
$ xmllint --shell file.xml <<EOF
setns x=xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/externalMetadata
cat //x:Version/text()
EOF

/ > setns x=xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/externalMetadata
/ > cat //x:Version/text()
 -------
2014.4.0.0008
/ >
```

But sadly, there's rubbish in the output, so :

```
$ xmllint --shell file.xml <<EOF | grep -Ev '^(/ *>| --+)'
setns x=xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/externalMetadata
cat //x:Version/text()
EOF
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
2014.4.0.0008
```

Another way :

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[namespace-uri()="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/externalMetadata" and local-name()="Version"]/text()' file.xml
```

Finally [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) is quite more advanced and it seems the proper tool here :

```
xml sel -N x="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/externalMetadata" -t -m "//x:Version/text()" -c . -n file.xml
```

And bonus (avaibility to use XPath 3) [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint)

```
saxon-lint --xpath 'declare default element namespace "xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/externalMetadata";//Version/text()' file.xml
```

Comment: This works, though I have no idea why. Is there a way of doing this where the solution is more easily adaptable to other elements (such as setting the namespace more to the root than the specific element)?

Comment: @sputnick Instead of recommending `local-name()`, you should rather show how declaring and using namespaces in `xmllint` works. Ignoring the namespace rarely is a good option.

Comment: You can use `xmllint ... | awk 'c&&!--c;/^ -------$/{c=1}'` to remove the garbage from xmllint's output.

Comment: Some other solutions provided seems better

Comment: Thank you for the help. I spent way too many hours looking at this last night coming to the same conclusion that if you want to set the NS you have to go into the xlint shell (which I don't want to do because this is in a script).

Comment: Added filtered with grep xmllint  solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error of "XPath set is empty" trying to output a string from a node.

So, following [this documentation](https://pages.lip6.fr/Jean-Francois.Perrot/XML-Int/Session2/XPath/), I found another way of writing it. (Note: I'm not an expert, I was just trying to find a solution.)

In your case, it would be:

```
xmllint externalmetadata.xml --xpath '//PackInfo/Version/text()'
```

I've tried the same with double quotes instead of single quotes, but had trouble. So with single quotes and writing the name of the file before the `--xpath` worked for me.